# Working with interactive-background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to get a parallax effect on my website's landing page. I used the [interactive_bg.js](https://github.com/peachananr/interactive_bg) plugin and working backwards from the [demo tutorial](https://onextrapixel.com/create-an-interactive-moving-backgroundobject-that-reacts-to-viewers-cursor/) I was finally able to get the picture I want with the desired effect.

Here's my code:
HTML -

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS -

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper { // this class isn't really needed but I thought it may help when putting other elements atop this div.
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ibg-bg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Js -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".bg").interactive_bg({
     strength: 20,
     scale: 1.00,
     contain: false,
     wrapContent: true
   });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".wrapper > .ibg-bg").css({
    width: $(window).outerWidth(),
    height: $(window).outerHeight()
  })
})
```

I reverse engineered the tutorial files to find this code.

Now the problem is, anything that I put into the `<div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">` messes up the picture. Any div I want to put after the `<div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">` div doesn't even show up on the screen but is rather behind the background image.

How do I put text and other divs **on** the `<div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">` div and more content after that div ends?

I have tried `z-index` and positioning (by looking at the code from the tutorial). It doesn't seem to work.

Also, the CSS only works when I put it in a `style` tag inside the `<head>` of the HTML. If I put the CSS in a separate file it doesn't work.
(I did link the CSS to the HTML correctly)

P.S refer to the tutorial I linked above, it'll get you an idea.

**UPDATE:**
I made some changes to the HTML and now I have text over the image. And the text isn't moving anymore but adds a white space on top. I tried margin but it didn't remove the white space. I still can't add anything below the image.
HTML-

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="main"> <h1> SOME TEXT </h1></div>
</body>
```

CSS -

```
#main{
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering around for a while it turned out to be a JS error. I had done a mistake in javascript while copying the script for the plugin execution.

Shout-out to @Triby for helping me out with the CSS, though that is a different thing and I will state it in another question.

Here's the working JS -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bg").interactive_bg({
    scale: 1.05,
    strength: 25,
    animationSpeed: "150ms"
  })
})
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".wrapper > .ibg-bg").css({
    width: $(window).outerWidth(),
    height: $(window).outerHeight()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the demo? **http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_bg_demo.html**

- wrapper div will take all the space available, width 100% and height 100%.
- wrapper div holds all the content, position absolute.
- ibg-bg div is just holds the background image and its not intended to have content inside, position absolute makes easy to put content over it; no need for z-index.
- Any other div inside wrapper div and after ibg-bg div will show on top.

How do you put text over the background?
As I said before, put that content inside the wrapper div and after the ib-bg div.

How do you put text or more content after that div?
Add your new content below wrapper div and start playing with css properties to adapt the demo to your preferences.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">
      <!-- You need this next div -->
      <div class="ibg-bg"></div>
      <div>This will appear over your background</div>
  </div>
  <div>This will appear below your background</div>
</body>
```

[Edit]
CSS Copied from demo.

```
#main {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[/edit]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Okay, so the div on my background (the one inside wrapper and after ibg-bg) is also moving with the background. How do I fix that?

Comment: Please update your html and css code, other way I can't figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: I cant seem to get it working... I'm not really that good with css. I used your exact HTML code, and the text on my background moves with it. And text which is supposed to be under it is on the top under the image. I got no idea what to do

Comment: Ok, please edit your answer to include your current HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Done.. please have a look at the markup. I also tried what you suggested but it had the same results

Comment: Add another div with class="ibg-bg" before your main div.

Comment: Something like this? <body>
  <div class="wrapper bg" data-ibg-bg="pics/Q.jpg">
    <div class="ibg-bg"></div>
    <div id="main"> <h1> SOME TEXT </h1></div>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: It didn't work. But I found something that does... look at the updated code in the question

Comment: Yes, just like that.